# Join in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to do this search below, but I'm receiving an error.

```
ViewBag.IDCONCESSAO = 
    from p in db.SINCO_CONCESSAO.ToList()
    join c in db.MUNICIPIOS_VIEW.ToList() on p.IDMUNICIPIO equals c.NOME_MUNICIPIO
    select new
        {
            Id = p.IDCONCESSAO,
            Nome = p.IDCONCESSAO + " - " + c.NOME_MUNICIPIO
        };
```

Error:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.
>   Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

What is incorrect?

Comment: Can you list out your mapping classes, etc for this as well? Need to see the entities in question to help.

Comment: Hi Jessica, you may want to consider removing the `.ToList()` from each line in the query. When the `ToList` is fired, it retrieves all the rows from the database and brings it into memory, so the `JOIN` isn't done on the database server, it is done on the web server (or locally if it's a windows program). This can cause huge performance issues if the tables are big enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in that line:

```
  join c in db.MUNICIPIOS_VIEW.ToList() on p.IDMUNICIPIO equals c.NOME_MUNICIPIO
```

I was doing a relation with different types, because IDMUNICIPIO is int and NOME_MUNICIPIO is string. When I changed to this, it worked:

```
 join c in db.MUNICIPIOS_VIEW.ToList() on p.IDMUNICIPIO equals c.ID_MUNICIPIO
```